# How to hide parent element based on child's text value

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want is to be able to search the DOM for a certain string. If the text is on the page hide certain elements and show others. The catch is the id's are given dynamically within a PHP foreach statement.

I've tried to search for an .exists() function specific to text. So far I've tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var string1 = 'string1',
        string2 = 'string2';

    if ($('li').children().text() === string1) {
        if ($('li').children().text() === string2) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    } else {
        if ($('li').children().text() === string2) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        } else {
            $(this).parent().show();
        }
    }
});
```

so what I'm looking for:

1) search page for string1.

2) if string1 exists on the page show the parent of the child element that contains string2 and hide any other string.

3) if it doesn't exists hide string1 and string2.

but that doesn't work. I'm not the greatest at Jquery/JS and in general I'm a beginner with it..

Comment: Could also provide a sample of your HTML please. Your first `if` statement seems redundant though, as you have the same logic under both conditions.

Comment: the html is generated dynamic with a foreach loop - I can add it but the only thing you'll see is $this->getTitle() etc.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve, because you have incorrect condition in your code.

Comment: see revised question

Comment: what you mean by _search page for string1_? search in all the document DOM?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yup!

Comment: Are you considering the text inside the li element the child? And the li the parent? Based off the fiddle you provided to Bas van Stein there are no children elements to any of your li elements. Also in your code $(this) refers to the document as your working in the scope of $(document).ready. You might want to include the sample HTML and give an exact example based on the HTML what result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a string contains another (sub)string you can use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp).
And check if it is not -1.

Using `each()` you can loop over all `li` elements. Taking your jsFiddle (provided in comment) into account, I got this result: http://jsfiddle.net/ub8c6smh/5/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var string1 = 'string1',
        string2 = 'string2';
    var string1exists= $('li').text().indexOf( string1)!==-1;
    console.log(string1exists);

    $('li').each(function () {
         if ($(this).text().indexOf( string2)!==-1 && string1exists==true) {
             // this child contains string 2
            $('li').hide(); //hide all others
            $(this).show();                    
        }
        if ($(this).text().indexOf( string2)!==-1 && string1exists==false) {
             // this child contains string 2
            $(this).hide();                    
        }
        if ($(this).text().indexOf( string1)!==-1 && string1exists==false) {
             // this child contains string 1
            $(this).hide();                    
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :( see revised question for a bit more info if needed

Comment: You need to loop over the children. Let me update my answer

Comment: upvote for suggesting the .each() though, I think that might be pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @TT120 is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ub8c6smh/4/ (PS: do not forget to include jQuery in jsfiddle)